# Do I need a full ordering on class K to use std::map<K, L>

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What requirements must std::map key classes meet to be valid keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573225/what-requirements-must-stdmap-key-classes-meet-to-be-valid-keys)

I want to use `std::map` as map from my class to another one. If I try the following code, I get an error "`undefined operator <`". Does it mean that I need an ordering on class `K` to use `map`? And does it have to be full ordering? And do I need all four ordering operators or `>` is enough?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct K {
    int i, j;

    K(int i, int j) : i(i), j(j){}

    friend bool operator==(const K& x, const K& y){ return (x.i==y.i)&&(x.j==y.j); }
    friend bool operator!=(const K& x, const K& y){ return !(x==y); }

/*  friend bool operator<(const K&x, const K&y){
        if(x.i<y.i) return true;
        if(x.i>y.i) return false;
        return x.j<y.j;
    }
    friend bool operator>(const K&x, const K&y){ return y<x; }
    friend bool operator<=(const K&x, const K&y){ return !(y<x); }
    friend bool operator>=(const K&x, const K&y){ return !(x<y); }
*/
};


int main(){
    map<K, float> m;
    m[K(1,2)]=5.4;
    if(m.find(K(1,2))!=m.end())
        cout << "Found: " << m[K(1,2)] << endl;
    else
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only need `operator<`, i.e. `operator<=`, `operator>` etc. are not required. Is that what you mean by full ordering? (And actually, if you don't want to code an `operator<`, you may pass a comparator function as third template argument.)

Comment: full = linear, i.e. always exactly one of `x>y`, `y>x` or `x==y` hold.

Comment: Oh, a _total_ ordering. No, actually, it's a strict weak ordering, same as what is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12419851/777186

Comment: Elements in a map must follow a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering)

Comment: so `operator>(const Q& x, const Q& y){return false;}` would suffice?

Comment: No, `operator<`. Nothing will ever look for any other.

Comment: @JanHudec I'm sorry, I meant that of course.

Comment: IF this is your real code, then use `std::pair<int,int>` instead of `K` - `std::pair` has all you need to use it as key in `map`

Comment: @PiotrNycz No, it is not. My real code is a template class with 3 parameters, one of them usually another template class. Simply too much unrelated stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, you need a way to compare elements (`operator<`) in order to use the std::map. One of the features of map is that it keeps its contents in sorted order, but to achieve this its need to know how to compare items.

You have three options to implement a comparison method:

1. Add `operator<` definition in K
2. Make a `comp` functor that know to how to compare two K elements and add this as a template parameter`map<K, float, comp> m`;

   ```
   struct comp {
       bool operator()(const K& first, const K& second) {
           /*****/
       }
   };
   ```
3. You can define the std::less specialization for K

   ```
   template<>  struct less<K>
   {
       bool operator()(const K& first, const K& second) {
           /*****/
       }
   };
   ```

And simple use `map<K, float> m;`

This works because by the template definition for map has the compare function set to std::less.

> template < class Key, class T, **class Compare = less**,
>              class Allocator = allocator > > class map

Comment: No, it does not have to be `operator<`. That's only one option.

Comment: @JanHudec and what are the other options?

Comment: @JanHudec My apologies I was slow at getting to that point. But yes your right and I added that info.

Comment: explicitly specializing std::less for your key, for example

Comment: I like the idea of making a functor, because I can order elements of `K`, but the ordering makes no "real" sense so defining `operator<` is frowned-upon.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks i added that bit of info.

Answer (score 4):

The elements in your map are referenced by a comparison function on the Key type you supply.
Either implicitly as [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) or explicitly as [third template argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

If you use a custom key type, you also need to supply an appropriate comparison function (or functional object) that imposes a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) on the keys. 
That is, if the keys appear equal

```
!(key1 < key2 || key2 < key1)
```

the items are considered equivalent.

Thus, if your comparison function only provides a [partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order) on the keys, elements may be considered equal that actually are different, and thereby their values might interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Just define `operator<`

Everything else is unnecessary for the purpose of `std::map` ordering.

Comment: It will work. The explanation is misleading as there are no "should"s nor "or"s.

Comment: Thanks. I've altered my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

An std::map needs simply an operator<. Implementations usually employ a "red-black" tree which can be built to only requires a < operator.

However you can use std::unordered_map exactly how you just did. It typically uses a generic hash function; you are free to supply your own hash function for it if suits your problem-space since C++11.

Comment: -1: `std::map` defaults to `operator<` since SGI initially designed STL! It never needed it and still does not need it.

Comment: @jogojapan I'm confused? I hit post and it had 2 downvotes? I suggested an unordered map right in the body...

Comment: @Robᵩ I think there was an error. As you see there aren't any edits to the answer, but it doesn't say what you said it does. I am very confused by this :-\

Comment: How the heck did I get downvoted before I even post a question?

Comment: Rewriting all of the body once you hit "post" is a bad idea. The answer gets immediately loaded for people who have the question open and they start commenting. Better delete it and write the correct answer.

Comment: @JanHudec There aren't any edits though! See no "last edited" line? This is weird!

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave - You hit post before you finished typing, then clicked edit. SO treats edits that happen fairly immediately as the original post.

Comment: Yes, that stack exchange feature is really weird. It collapses edits made within 5 minutes, but that is more than enough for people to comment and than the comments make no sense, because the commented version does not exist at all.

Comment: I would swear on my life I didn't hit edit, but then if I made such a careless mistake as the comments noted, perhaps my mind is playing tricks on me.

Comment: @JanHudec Also, SGI didn't design STL. It was designed by Alexander Stepanov and Meng Lee, and the first report on it was a paper from HP. SGI just released a famous version of it.